# Trying to make d3js transitions shrink or grow to the next value

Tags: d3.js, transition

I am trying to transition the widths of a bar chart I created.  The problem is the the bars grow from 0 to n during the transition.  How can I make the bars either grow OR  shrink to the new value for width?  Here is my jsfiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/LAG2r/2/

```
var codes = d3.range("A".charCodeAt(0), "Z".charCodeAt(0)).concat(d3.range("a".charCodeAt(0), "z".charCodeAt(0))),
    chars = [];

codes.forEach(function (c) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(c);
    chars.push(chr);
});

function random(size) {

    var string = '',
        len = chars.length,
        start = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);

    return d3.shuffle(chars.slice(start, start + size)).join('');
}

function createData(size) {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data.push({
            name: random(6),
            value: Math.random() * 1000
        });
    }
    return data;
}
var svg = d3.select('#yo').append('svg:svg').append('g:svg');



var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([0, 490])
    .nice();

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(50))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, 490], .2);

setInterval(function () {

    var dataTarget = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(createData(50), function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });
    dataTarget.exit().remove();
    dataTarget.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())

        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
        return y(i);
    })
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return x(Math.min(0, d.value));
    })
        .transition()
        .attr("width", function (d, i) {
        return d.value;
    });

}, 2000);
```

Comment: You seem to be experiencing the same issue I'm seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15651056/173225. I tried to add the update selection to your fiddle, but it still replaces all the generated DOM elements each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here :

Your key function given to .data (function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })) tells d3 to associate each data point by its name. Every time you refresh it, you are passing in 50 new data objects with different random names, so D3 loses the association. So every time you refresh, all the data that was there is going into the "exit()" data join and the new data is going into the "enter()" data join. If we don't provide the key function, d3 will base off index, which I think is closer to what we want here.

Secondly, you don't have an "update" data join - only an enter which has a transition. We need to add this at the bottom :

```
dataTarget
.transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr("width", function (d, i) {
    return d.value;
});
```

I've revised the jsfiddle here with what I think is your goal : http://jsfiddle.net/LAG2r/3/

Source : http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Comment: Ahh....I see.  So my next question is NOT providing the key (going strictly by index) the way I was supposed to do it OR  should I take the existing 50 objects, update them, and reapply the data().enter()?  And, should I be calling the transition twice as you have it here for something like this (using an updating functionality)?  I feel like there needs to be some redundancy in code for an example like this to work.  Thanks!

Comment: The "transition()" simply tells d3 to tween between beginning and ending values, which is why both the enter/update are 'animated'.

If you are actually updating data (rather than generating a new set of randomized data), you would probably have a key function to associate the data.

Comment: I guess my question is actually why call transition() twice in my code versus once.   I removed the second call to transition and noticed only one transition but no subsequent ones.  Am I crazy to think one transition() call should be enough per interval (versus two)? Thanks again.

Comment: The transition() call specifies that both your enter and update joins should tween. I've updated this jsfiddle to remove the transition() call - it's not necessary for them to update : http://jsfiddle.net/LAG2r/4/ . I'd encourage you to read that link about from Mike Bostock about data joins.